Ubuntu 24.04 freezes when compiling code with LLVM-14
I have been running into an issue over the past 2 weeks where compiling my work codebase (bazel build system) causes Ubuntu to freeze completely. The only way out is to force-restart. I have tried both rolling back and upgrading my kernel version, but to no avail. I was initially running Ubuntu 22.04 when this started to happen. But after the kernel rollback failed to resolve, I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04, but the issue persists. Current kernel version is 6.8.0-31-generic
I can also confirm that this is not a RAM issue, as I have sufficient RAM (64GB) and swap (64GB) to compile the code, which consumes at most ~35GB during compilation.
Soon after each freeze, the following 2 files are written to /var/crash:
_usr_lib_llvm-14_bin_clang.0.crash
_usr_share_code_code.1000.crash
(The contents of these are too large to include here)
The output of sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e is:
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 kernel: eth0: renamed from vethf669093
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <info>  [1716663888.0462] device (veth6c2ea4a): carrier: link connected
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 kernel: br-c6f9d326fe7f: port 1(veth6c2ea4a) entered blocking state
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 kernel: br-c6f9d326fe7f: port 1(veth6c2ea4a) entered forwarding state
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <info>  [1716663888.3024] manager: (veth085b90e): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/55)
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 kernel: br-c6f9d326fe7f: port 11(vethdf1ed24) entered blocking state
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 kernel: br-c6f9d326fe7f: port 11(vethdf1ed24) entered disabled state
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 kernel: vethdf1ed24: entered allmulticast mode
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 kernel: vethdf1ed24: entered promiscuous mode
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <info>  [1716663888.3028] manager: (vethdf1ed24): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/56)
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 dockerd[2694]: time="2024-05-25T15:04:48.304728113-04:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers"
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 containerd[1990]: time="2024-05-25T15:04:48.321510869-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.event.v1.publisher\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.event.v1
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 containerd[1990]: time="2024-05-25T15:04:48.321572398-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.shutdown\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.inter>
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 containerd[1990]: time="2024-05-25T15:04:48.321579868-04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.ttrpc.v1.task\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.ttrpc.v1
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 containerd[1990]: time="2024-05-25T15:04:48.321661607-04:00" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/fc64004de25b2ed76f5>
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 systemd[1]: Started docker-fc64004de25b2ed76f5d693d57958764435ed3812bc685f7c7b4028e6a1c3bd4.scope - libcontainer container fc64004de25b2ed76f5d693d57958764435ed3812bc685f7c7b4028e6a1c3bd4.
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 systemd[1]: var-lib-docker-overlay2-864f23f958d51ff7dba1c19e7ecdb66813eec8d397150d5b1891629d4129e33f-merged.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 kernel: eth0: renamed from veth085b90e
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <info>  [1716663888.4103] device (vethdf1ed24): carrier: link connected
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 kernel: br-c6f9d326fe7f: port 11(vethdf1ed24) entered blocking state
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 kernel: br-c6f9d326fe7f: port 11(vethdf1ed24) entered forwarding state
May 25 15:04:48 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663888.4105] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::5934:5dae:178:7215]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:04:50 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663890.4136] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::a556:ae76:b80:60af]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:04:52 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663892.4138] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::1c2a:aa23:15fe:28d5]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:04:54 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663894.4156] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::d0cc:e577:6915:65a6]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:04:56 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663896.4163] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::e5e9:2e39:9fb6:c134]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:04:57 niran90 systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-39b98758c47e5011b2660ec25888e231ef6b646a133ebe5c0609cf88b1dd52bc-runc.dEcFGA.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 25 15:04:58 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663898.4175] ipv6ll[b91606956f983c79,ifindex=2]: changed: no IPv6 link local address to retry after Duplicate Address Detection failures (back off)
May 25 15:05:01 niran90 CRON[10497]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
May 25 15:05:01 niran90 CRON[10498]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
May 25 15:05:01 niran90 CRON[10497]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 25 15:05:07 niran90 systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-39b98758c47e5011b2660ec25888e231ef6b646a133ebe5c0609cf88b1dd52bc-runc.LeuIkr.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 25 15:05:08 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663908.4207] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::6018:4ef1:60b6:53a2]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:05:08 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663908.4207] l3cfg[c247cd07f7643ce5,ifindex=2]: unable to configure IPv6 route: type unicast fe80::/64 dev 2 metric 1024 mss 0 rt-src ipv6ll
May 25 15:05:10 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663910.4211] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::5934:5dae:178:7215]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:05:12 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663912.4236] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::a556:ae76:b80:60af]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:05:14 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663914.4257] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::1c2a:aa23:15fe:28d5]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:05:16 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663916.4277] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::d0cc:e577:6915:65a6]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:05:18 niran90 systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-39b98758c47e5011b2660ec25888e231ef6b646a133ebe5c0609cf88b1dd52bc-runc.dKZQto.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 25 15:05:18 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663918.4297] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::e5e9:2e39:9fb6:c134]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:05:20 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663920.4315] ipv6ll[b91606956f983c79,ifindex=2]: changed: no IPv6 link local address to retry after Duplicate Address Detection failures (back off)
May 25 15:05:30 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663930.4427] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::6018:4ef1:60b6:53a2]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:05:30 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663930.4427] l3cfg[c247cd07f7643ce5,ifindex=2]: unable to configure IPv6 route: type unicast fe80::/64 dev 2 metric 1024 mss 0 rt-src ipv6ll
May 25 15:05:32 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663932.4437] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::5934:5dae:178:7215]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:05:34 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663934.4457] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::a556:ae76:b80:60af]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:05:36 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663936.4477] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::1c2a:aa23:15fe:28d5]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:05:38 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663938.4496] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::d0cc:e577:6915:65a6]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:05:39 niran90 systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-39b98758c47e5011b2660ec25888e231ef6b646a133ebe5c0609cf88b1dd52bc-runc.dNrVMM.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 25 15:05:40 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663940.4516] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::e5e9:2e39:9fb6:c134]: failure 13 (Permission denied - ipv6: IPv6 is disabled on this device)
May 25 15:05:42 niran90 NetworkManager[1418]: <warn>  [1716663942.4535] ipv6ll[b91606956f983c79,ifindex=2]: changed: no IPv6 link local address to retry after Duplicate Address Detection failures (back off)
lines 970-1019/1019 (END)


I have tried enabling IPv6 at a kernel level, but this did not fix the issue. Although IPv6 was again automatically disabled after a subsequent reboot, so I am not sure if I did this correctly. Regardless, I had not previously tampered with anything to do with IPv6, so I am unsure how this could suddenly be related to it.
Any insight into resolving this issue would be much appreciated!
